# How to determine whether an object is a file or a folder

Tags: c#, file, file-io, filepath

I am trying to determine whether a given path points to a file or a directory. Currently my logic is very plain and involves the following check

```
if (sourcePath.Contains(".")) // then treat this path as a file
```

The problem above is that folder names can have periods in them too. I would like to be able to ascertain that a given path is that of a file without having to try and instantiate a filestream type and attempting to access it or anything like that.

Is there someway to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the [File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) method:

> If path describes a directory, this
>   method returns false

So:

```
if (File.Exists(sourcePath))
{
    // then treat this path as a file
}
```

There's also the [Directory.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx) method and the following example is given in the documentation:

```
if(File.Exists(path)) 
{
    // This path is a file
    ProcessFile(path); 
}               
else if(Directory.Exists(path)) 
{
    // This path is a directory
    ProcessDirectory(path);
}
else 
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a valid file or directory.", path);
}
```

Comment: @Erno, that's true but if the OP intention is to manipulate this file then probably it is a safe check. Also if neither the file nor the directory exists given a string it is impossible to say whether it is a file or directory.

Comment: @Darin: it depends on where he got the sourcePath from.

Comment: @Erno, what do you mean? As I said if neither the file nor the directory exists given a string (no matter where you got it from) you are unable to tell whether this string represents a file or directory.

Answer (score 3):

C#:

```
public bool IsFolder(string path)
{
    return ((File.GetAttributes(path) & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory);
}
```

VB.Net:

```
Public Function IsFolder(path As String) As Boolean
    Return ((File.GetAttributes(path) And FileAttributes.Directory) = FileAttributes.Directory)
End Function
```

This function throws a `File not found exception` if the file does not exists. So you have to catch it (or use Darin Dimitrow's approach).

```
Try
    Dim isExistingFolder As Boolean = IsFolder(path)
    Dim isExistingFile = Not isExistingFolder 
Catch fnfEx As FileNotFoundException
    '.....
End Try
```

Comment: You can make this method even shorter in .NET 4: `return File.GetAttributes(path).HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory);`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var isDirectory = (File.GetAttributes(path) & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory;
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.IO.File.Exists("yourfilenamehere")` will do the trick.  This'll return false if the path isn't for a file.  It'll also return false if the path doesn't exist, so be careful.

Answer (score 0):

by googling, I found this:

```
public bool IsFolder(string path)
{
    return ((File.GetAttributes(path) & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory);
}
```

then you can call the function as follows:

```
// Define a test path
string filePath = @"C:\Test Folder\";

if (IsFolder(filePath)){
    MessageBox.Show("The given path is a folder.");
}
else {
    MessageBox.Show("The given path is a file.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> RtnList = new List<string>();
foreach (string Line in ListDetails)
{
    if (line.StartsWith("d") && !line.EndsWith("."))
    {
        RtnList.Add(line.Split(' ')[line.Split(' ').Length - 1] );


    }
}
```

Comment: was this answer mistakenly filed for this question?  I don't see the correlation.